# Angular 15 Ckeditor 5 scroll to bottom or to current cursor position

Tags: angular, ckeditor5

I'm inserting dynamic text into ckeditor 5 and setting the cursor position, but its not scrolling into current cursor position. below is what I tried. didn't seem to work

```
this.noteEditor.editorInstance.setData(editorData.replace(regExMatch, res.Result.Text.trim()));
          this.noteEditor.editorInstance.model.change((writer:any) => {
            writer.setSelection(writer.createPositionAt( this.noteEditor.editorInstance.model.document.getRoot(), 'end' ));
            // this.noteEditor.editorInstance.editing.view.scrollToTheSelection({viewportOffset:300,alignToTop:false})
            // console.log(`consult-notes.component::this.noteEditor.editorInstance - `,this.noteEditor.editorInstance);
            // document.getElementById("ck-scroll").scrollIntoView();
          });
```

Note. I just want to scroll to bottom of the ckeditor view on dynamic content addition.

[image: not scrolling]

stackblitz link to the issue -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jjjltl?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing the problem? Ideally in a online code editor like [Stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com).

Comment: @Cuzy I have added the link in the question.